# Como trabaja el JobIntentService para Android Oreo y pre Oreo?

Tags: android, android-studio, servicio

Estuve investigando y leí que es necesario o mejor dicho, recomendable la implementación de `JobIntentService` por la aparición de `android` `Oreo` y sus limitaciones o nuevas restricciones con respecto a los servicios en `Background`, dice que la misma es encargada de verificar o gestionar los servicios o acciones de los mismos (que es lo que no me queda claro) y ejecutarlos en una cola de tareas según la versión de `android`, lo que hasta ahora no consigo es un ejemplo básico de la implementación de esta, alguien podría brindarme un poco de orientación con respecto a esto? gracias de antemano

Answer (score 0):

Hola estaba buscando igual información sobre ello, y encontre un ejemplo aunque la web esta en ingles, espero te sirva igual que a mi:
[Link](https://androidwave.com/working-with-jobintentservice/)